# How to begin programming with STM32 Discovery

Tags: stm32f4, ide

I am a complete beginner to Microcontroller programming. I have a new STM32F4 Discovery board and I am clueless on how to begin with a simple blinking LED program.

I have installed Eclipse with the GNU ARM plugin and now I am wondering what to do next. I have found a few tutorials online but most of them use other IDEs than Eclipse. I am not sure if Eclipse is the best IDE for uC programming. If yes, could someone point me to tutorials for such programming for beginners.

Comment: were you able to run built in demonstration [From ST](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/user_manual/DM00037368.pdf)

Comment: The following is stated in the user manual `The STM32F4DISCOVERY firmware applications are provided in one single package and
supplied in one single zip file. The extraction of the zip file generates one folder,
STM32F4-Discovery_FW_VX.Y.Z,` but I am unable to find the zip anywhere in [this](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM116/SC959/SS1532/LN1848/PF252419) link. Am I looking at the wrong page? @Umar

Comment: Scroll down to "Related tools and software".

Comment: Look here http://stm32f4-discovery.com/

Answer (score 1):

Click [here](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF259243)

and click on **Download** button below. Later you can extract the files..

[image]

That is all i can do.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a toolchain up and running is the first step.  For the STM32F4, I recommend CooCox.  It's the most straightforward to get you up and running, and will use the standard CMSIS HAL for the STM32 -- which is probably the most extensible way to program the ARM Cortex processors such that what you learn will easily transfer to other ARM Cortex manifestations.

Comment: How about IAR workbench as the IDE. My company has a license for it. Would you recommend using IAR workbench over CooCox?

Comment: IAR is fine.  The free versions are limited in terms of the size of the application, I believe, but with reasonable limits.  It's certainly not crippleware.  Full versions are very good.